# How to stop accepting requests when you are upgrading your rails site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Whenever I want to deploy my new version of rails app. I want to stop stop accepting requests from client side.

Example: **User** is filling form. In the back I am upgrading my rails web (not the rails or ruby version). When user submits the form while upgrade is happening or has happened, I want to show something like 'Web site has upgraded, please try again'. Is it actually possible, or some way to achieve it.

**Edited:** Let's say user is filling a big form for 10 minutes (has not pressed submit yet). Our upgrade took 1 minute and when user submits, want to show the message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following  gem(if your application is not Heroku appplication) :

https://github.com/biola/turnout

It works well

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to switch the site into maintenance mode before such big release. In maintenance mode, all functionality is offline and server replies with the same static html to all requests ("the site is under maintenance, please try again later" or something).

For example, in heroku [this is built-in](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode).

Before the big release, you enable the maintenance mode

```
heroku maintenance:on
```

Do your release, upgrade database, etc, then bring the site back online

```
heroku maintenance:off
```

If you are not on heroku, you either have to implement this yourself (the idea is super-simple) or maybe there's a gem for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Site is on amazon. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into making nginx serving the maintenance page and you have to build a html page to be served by nginx

Please read the following post on how to make nginx serve the maintenance page

http://mensfeld.pl/2014/08/nginx-and-puma-behind-maintenance-mode-for-rackrails-applications-with-capistrano/